# How to use onkeyup and onkeydown for an input tag?

Tags: javascript, keydown, keyup

I have an input field and i want to do some calculations depending upon keyup and keydown. 
I tried using onkeyup and onkeydown functions, but when i press a key from the keyboard, it prints both "keyup" as well as "keydown" in the console. Is there any other function which differentiates keyup and keydown events seperately?  My input tags are inside the html table.
This is my code

```
  $('table input').on('keyup', function(){
      console.log("keyup");
  });

  $('table input').on('keydown', function(){
      console.log("keydown");
  });
```

Comment: Change "input" to "keydown" or "keyup"?

Comment: I tried it. but it doens't work. @Lewis

Comment: There's no reason why it shouldn't. There's something else wrong with your code if that doesn't work. Have a look at the [Keyboard Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) documentation on MDN.

Comment: @RhugvedaDesai Try using my code... If it doesn't work, would you try making a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would suggest not to mix jQuery and pure JavaScript. All you need is to add the `keyup keydown` instead of `input`:

```js
$('table input').on('keyup keydown', function() {
  var parent = $(this).closest('tr');
  var value = parent.find('[name="item_value[]"]').val();
  var amount = parent.find('[name="quantity[]"]').val();
  var total_cost = value * amount;
  parent.find('[name="total_cost[]"]').val(total_cost);
  total_value = total_value + total_cost;
  $('#total').val(total_value);
});
```

Comment: JQuery is JavaScript.

Comment: @JacobGaiski I meant the way... You know that I am a JavaScript geek.  How better could I have explained that in my answer? Maybe, to keep up with the way of writing or something? Or replacing that with *jQuery syntax and pure JavaScript syntax*?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I guess you were saying that if they're using jQuery, they might as well use it everywhere for consistency rather than changing between using and not-using. I.e, there's no point mixing `.val()` and `.value`.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check! @PraveenKumarPurushothaman

Comment: @RhugvedaDesai The code you have sent actually executes. If you were able to show us a [mcve], we can see where it goes wrong, like the selector or something might go wrong, so...

Answer (score 1):

change `input` to `keyup`:

```
$('table input').on('keyup', function(){
    var parent = $(this).closest('tr');
    var value = parent.find('[name="item_value[]"]').val();
    var amount = parent.find('[name="quantity[]"]').val();
    var total_cost = value * amount;
    parent.find('[name="total_cost[]"]').val(total_cost);
    total_value = total_value + total_cost;
    document.getElementById('total').value = total_value;
});
```

Read more about [keyup](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need keyup and keydown, both will trigger with the same keycode.

You should use one or the other. The difference will be a delay in processing.

For instance, if you do KeyUp, depending on the length of time that the key is held down for, KeyUp will only trigger once that key is released - as opposed to KeyDown.

Referencing W3Schools, you can acheive this via:
(Where keycode = the Octal value defined in ASCII (https://www.genuinecoder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/asciifull.gif)

(Also by running this example, you will notice that fast keyDowns and keyUps can cause conflicts within processing. You should use one or the other, never both.)

```
$("input").keyup(function(e){
   alert(e.keyCode);
    $("input").css("background-color", "pink");
});
$("input").keydown(function(e){
    alert(e.keyCode);
    $("input").css("background-color", "pink");
});
```